# One knight and one queen on an infinite chess-board (a simple game)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, chessboard, infinite-games

On an infinite chessboard, player A places the queen wherever they want. Then, player B places the knight wherever they want. Finally, the game starts.

The main rule is that any square where player A places their queen is removed from the chessboard.

> Can A always check-mate B (if the both are playing their best strategies)?

A check-mate here is a position in which A attacks B’s knight, giving it nowhere to jump because the squares on which it can jump are all removed.

The second rule is that queen cannot "go over" (cannot "hover over") the removed squares, and cannot attack the knight "over the removed squares".

The third rule is that the knight cannot capture the queen.

So, the queen should be careful in her strategy, because if she removes "too many" squares, that would restrict her possible movements over the board, even though she can travel long distances.

On the other hand, the knight jumps only short distances.

Comment: Well, $A$ can start in the upper left hand corner and systematically delete squares in a spiral towards the center, trapping the knight.

Comment: @lulu What is the meaning of "upper left hand corner" if we are on the infinite chessboard?

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was infinite.  So, then, this is a variation of [Conway's Angel Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem).  Hence, possibly difficult.

Comment: @lulu But decidable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  There must be a winning strategy for one or the other player.  But, Conway's problem is fairly hard.  I have not reviewed any of the accepted proofs that the $2-$dim angel can always win (in your variant, the knight is similar to the angel), so that bodes well for your knight.  Indeed, your devil (the queen) is quite a bit weaker than Conway's but then your knight is (slightly) weaker then his angel too.  My guess is that your knight always wins, and I'd try to adapt one of the known resolutions of the Conway game.

Comment: To be precise:  Conway's devil can move anywhere at will, your queen can only make the usual queen moves AND she can be thwarted by her own obstructions.  That's a lot weaker.  Your knight, on the other hand, can only make knight moves where the $k-$angel can do whatever a king can do in $k-$moves.

Comment: @lulu So, in my game, the queen is "much weaker" than the devil in Conway´s and the knight is "not-much weaker" than the 3-angel in Conway´s? Yes, it seems that the knight will always win.

Comment: That's my view.  Of course, it's a very informal argument and I wouldn't accept it as a proof.  Still, it's a good enough argument that I'd start by assuming it was right and try to adapt the actual proofs accordingly.

Comment: @lulu It seems that the only way to make this more interesting is to edit the question and allow that queen goes over the removed squares.

Comment: @Grešnik the queen will always win

Comment: it is at least certain that the queen can never loose